# I keep trying to do a rankx in PBI, but it keep returning "Circular Dependency."

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to Power BI and I am trying to do a rankx to determine the ranking of instock % by vendors.

I have three columns: vendor, count, and instock. I created a third column below to calculate my instock % :

Instock % = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(sum('In Stock'[Instock]),SUM('In Stock'[Count])))

I then try the following to rank my vendors by their instock %, but return "A circular dependency was detected: In Stock[Instock %], In Stock[rank vendor], In Stock[Instock %]."

: rank vendor = RANKX(ALL('In Stock'[vendor]),'In Stock'[Instock %],,DESC)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to user measures in this case to avoid circular dependencies.

First, instead of current calculated column Instock % you can create the measure with the same DAX you currently use for your column:

```
Measure Instock % = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(sum('In Stock'[Instock]),SUM('In Stock'[Count])))
```

Secondly, you can create a ranking measure, replacing the reference to calculated column from your original DAX with the reference to the new measure:

```
Measure  rank vendor = RANKX(ALL('In Stock'[vendor]),'In Stock'[Measure Instock %],,DESC)
```

It works on my sample data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Arthur! I did what you said and there is no circular dependency, but it only returns 1s.

Comment: @Greg Do you add "Vendor" column to the table as well? It needs to be there to make this solution work. Here is how it looks on my sample data (I used "Enter Data" feature to have 3 sample rows): https://ibb.co/mFh5srk

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Measure  rank vendor = RANKX(ALL('In Stock'),'In Stock'[Measure Instock %], DESC)
```

It's very frustrating!